# How to get the position of mouse when clicked in a game window using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I don't want to get the cursor position all the time, but only when the mouse is clicked. So far the only python library i could find can do this is the pynput library. But it fail to detect mouse clicks from inside a game window, when a video game is being run. How can I get the mouse click position from inside the game window (don't need to be relative position)?

Comment: Where is the game running exactly? On the browser?

Comment: Game is running in a separate window. Not in browser. I run it by clicking an .exe.

Comment: games may use direct access to keyboard, mouse, display (usinig ie. DiretX) but modules like `pynput` uses standard functions in `system` (`Windows`) - so it may need more work with some specialized modules for `Windows` but  I don't use `Windows` to help.